# fundamental solution of the laplace Beltrami operator

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

It is well know that $s(z,z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \ln \vert z-z_0\vert$ satisfies $\Delta_z s=\delta_{z_0}$ in dimension $2$. Does any one have a reference when we consider a general metric $g$ on an open set of $R^2$? that is to say which is the solution of $(\Delta_g)_z s=\delta_{z_0}$

Answer (score 5):

In general there is no explicit expression, but under some mild conditions on the metric, you know they exist, and you know their qualitative behaviour. For reference, I suggest *Some nonlinear problems in Riemannian geometry* by Thierry Aubin.

Comment: Example:
for instance considering $g = \frac{d\theta^2}{r^2} + \frac{dr^2}{c^2}$ where $c>0$, then $s(z,0)= \frac{1}{2\pi c} \ln (\vert z\vert)$ but since i don't know the isometry of $(R^2,g)$, i can't deduce from this the general formula. Have you any idea how to proceed in that case? or how to get asymptotic?

Comment: @user79365: Aubin's book *Some nonlinear problems in Riemannian geometry* has some material on this.

Comment: @Ana When the manifold is highly symmetric, such as a sphere or hyperbolic space, an explicit formula may be found.  In general, don't expect it. Take a look at the book timur suggested in a comment. (Of which you were not automatically notified).

Comment: @Ana: Of course in general there is no isometry.  For asymptotics, assuming you want to know how it blows up locally, you would compare the local metric with some flattened version of the metric, for which you know good deal. Please consult Aubin's book.

Comment: thx for answer and references.

Comment: @Ana: If you find the answer useful, please vote up the answer by clicking the up arrow on the left side of the answer.