# Asymptotics of Green's function of laplacian

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $ \Omega $ be a domain in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ with a Riemannian metric $ g $, and let $\Delta $ be the laplace-beltrami operator induced by the metric, with dirichlet boundary conditions. For $ x,y \in \Omega $, let $ d(x,y) $ be the geodesic distance between $ x$ and $ y$. The green's function $ G(x,y) $ can be written as:
$$
G(x,y) = -\frac{1}{4 \pi} \log(d(x,y)^2) + \omega(x,y)
$$
where $\omega $ is some harmonic function that corrects for the boundary condition. Now for $ x$ and $ y $ close by one can write:
$$
d(x,y)^2 = g_{ij} (x-y)^i (x-y)^j + O((x-y)^3)
$$
Then one can write:
$$
G(x,y) =  -\frac{1}{4 \pi} \log(g_{ij} (x-y)^i (x-y)^j) + f(x,y)
$$
where $ f(x,y) $ is continuous.

I would be grateful if someone provide some clarification/reference on these facts, which I believe to be roughly true, but have never seen studied formally.

Comment: Related: [fundamental solution of the laplace Beltrami operator](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/413614/85506).